# UPDATING column with column from different table with no correlation between the tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.

- one is called tcolor which has 2 columns. One is called "ID" and the other is called "color" the color column is filled with hex color values. the ID column is all null values.
- I have another table in the same database called testg. testg has only one column called "ID".

I want to UPDATE (not INSERT) tcolor's ID column using testg's ID column.

How would I do that without getting the ORA-01427 error?

Also, to get the IDs into testg, I used this query below. Is there a way to change this query into an UPDATE statement so that I wont have to pull one column for one table into the other.

What I mean is, taking this query, converting it to an update statement, so that I can directly update my tcolor ID column.

```
INSERT INTO testg 
            (id) 
SELECT DISTINCT terr_id 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT jta.terr_id, 
                        jta.name, 
                        low_value_char, 
                        comparison_operator, 
                        high_value_char, 
                        jtva.last_update_date, 
                        jtva.creation_date 
        FROM   jtf_terr_values_all jtva, 
               jtf_terr_qual_all jtqa, 
               jtf_terr_all jta 
        WHERE  jtva.terr_qual_id = jtqa.terr_qual_id 
               AND jtqa.terr_id = jta.terr_id 
               AND jta.end_date_active > SYSDATE 
               AND jta.name LIKE 'US%' 
               AND low_value_char IS NOT NULL 
               AND comparison_operator IN ( '=' ) 
               AND Regexp_like (low_value_char, '^[[:digit:]]+$') 
        ORDER  BY 6 DESC);
```

Comment: sql server or oracle? choose one tag

Comment: which relations there is between the two tables  ?

Comment: Is an improvment but still same problems as I describe in your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403491/updating-column-with-column-from-different-table-with-no-correlation-between-the). You have 3 tables in your sub query and you dont explain those, you dont have any  `color` colum. And you dont include any sample data and expected ouput.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Say tcolor table has the following ID: 1,2,3,4 and the query you shown gives the following result: 100, 500, 200,  basing on this example please explain how do you want to update values in tcolor ? Which value must be updated with which one ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE column after Altering table in orcale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398728/update-column-after-altering-table-in-orcale)

Comment: Hey Anika, in general posting the same question again (on the same day no less) is unnecessary and really bad manners. The proper behavior is to edit/update your original post.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, you have a table (testg) and you want to be able to assign / link a distinct color to each id in that table, but that assignment is arbitrary.

I'd go with a plain loop. I assume there's enough color entries that you don't run out. You could make it smarter by exiting the loop once it stops finding rows to update.

```
declare
    cursor c_1 is
    select distinct testg.id
    from testg;
begin
    for r_1 in c_1 loop
        update tcolor
        set id = r_1.id
        where id is null
        and rownum = 1;
    end loop;
    commit;
end;
/
```